# Checking whether a foreign relationship exists

Tags: foreign-key, sqlite

I have a couple of tables within an SQLite v3.37 meant to track `Users`, `Roles`, and `Permissions`.

For the sake of the question, the `users` has just an `id` and an `email`. `roles` and `permissions` are also simple, with just an `id` and a `roleName` and `permName` respectively.

```
CREATE TABLE permissions (id integer primary key not null, permName text unique not null, dateCreated text default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, dateUpdated text default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

I have two auxiliary tables, `userRoles` and `rolePerms` which track what roles a user has been assigned, and what permissions have been assigned to each role respectively.

```
CREATE TABLE userRoles (userID integer not null, roleID integer not null, FOREIGN KEY (userID) REFERENCES users(rowid), FOREIGN KEY (roleID) REFERENCES roles(id));
```

Here is a rough diagram of the schema:

[image: A database schema diagram]

I am trying to create an SQL query that from an email address and a `permName`, determine if that user has been granted a role with that permission.

I have tried writing a query something like this:

```
SELECT users.rowid, users.email, roles.rowid, roles.roleName, permissions.rowid, permissions.permName, userRoles.*, rolePerms.* FROM users
    INNER JOIN userRoles on userRoles.userID=users.rowid AND userRoles.roleID=roles.roleID 
    INNER JOIN rolePerms on rolePerms.roleID=roles.rowid 
    WHERE users.email = 'doug@gmail.ca' AND permName='testPermission';
```

But this query obviously isn't getting the job done. I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40129475/how-to-inner-join-4-tables) about joining 4 tables, but those tables are all related to a single table, not two like the schema I am using.

EDIT: I believe the following query to be working:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(permName) FROM users INNER JOIN userRoles ON userRoles.userID=users.rowID INNER JOIN roles ON userRoles.roleID=roles.id INNER JOIN rolePerms ON rolePerms.roleID=roles.id INNER JOIN permissions ON permissions.id=rolePerms.permID WHERE users.email='doug@gmail.ca';
```

The big change is to reference `roles` via a JOIN ON `userRoles`, otherwise the SQL query is not aware of the table(?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is almost correct, you just need to join with the permissions table as well, plus remove some confusion about column names and remove an extra join condition:

```
SELECT users.rowid, users.email, roles.id, roles.roleName, permissions.id, permissions.permName, userRoles.*, rolePerms.* 
FROM users
INNER JOIN userRoles ON userRoles.userID=users.rowid
INNER JOIN roles ON roles.id=userRoles.roleId
INNER JOIN rolePerms ON rolePerms.roleID=roles.id
INNER JOIN permissions ON permissions.id=rolePerms.permID
WHERE users.email= 'doug@gmail.ca' AND permissions.permName='testPermission';
```

Comment: For some reason, I am getting a "no such column: roles.id" when running this query. However when running `.schema roles`, I can clearly see there is a column named "id"

Comment: If I change `roles.id, roles.roleName` to `roles.*` in the query, then I am told that there is 'no such table: roles'. My database is not corrupt or anything, as I checked with `PRAGMA integrity_check;`

Comment: ©JLCarveth Apologies, I had forgotten to join with the roles table. I've updated the query in the answer. Does that work now?